# Is there a way to increase the frame rate of tkvideo module

Tags: python, frame-rate

I was wondering if there was a way to increase the frame rate of mp4 files in the tkvideo module. I am trying to display videos in my root and I am able to but the frame rate is very low I've messed with the resolution a bit to see if that had any effect but to no avail thankyou in advanced.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1080x720')
my_label = Label(root)
my_label.pack()
player = tkvideo(r"C:\Users\Kameron Seals\Desktop\Python codes\Test\Assets\Test.mp4", my_label, loop = 1, size = (1080,720))
player.play()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you're saying that your file **contains a higher framerate** than what tk is currently displaying? Or are you trying to run through the available frames _faster_ (like a fast-forward feature?)?

Comment: Yeah my file is around 60 frames but the output that tk is displaying is considerably slower, it might be that the file is kinda big but that'd be my only guess.